# Javascript Communicating with Python

Tags: javascript, python

I am attempting to send data from a Javascript program to a python program using python -m http.server as a means to run it locally. When I run it, the error message I get is:
[HTTP/1.1 501 Unsupported method ('POST')
Here is the useful portion of my javascript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",() => {

  document.querySelector("#search_button").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    document.getElementById("company").innerHTML = document.getElementById("search").value;
  });

  document.querySelector("#week").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    var time = 1;
    fetch("/yahooFinanceAPI.py", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers:{'Content': 'application/JSON'},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        'Company' : document.getElementById("search").value,
        'Time' : time
      })
    }).then(function(response)
    {
      console.log(document.getElementById("search").value);
    })
  });
```

Here is the useful python:

```
@bp.route('/SecurityBenefit.js', methods = ['POST'])
def get_post_javascript_data():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json()
        ticker = data['Company']
        timespan = data['Time']
        print (ticker)
        print (timespan)
    return getPlot(ticker, timespan)
```

Does the python program need to run in the background for the program to register? Do I need to implement a do_POST function in my python?

Comment: Can you explain the whole routes situation here? Your javascript is making a POST request to /yahooFinanceAPI.py and your python is listening for the route of /SecurityBenefit.js . So where exactly does the python respond to the POST request at /yahooFinanceAPI.py ?

Comment: I don't need it to. The program adds a plot to the folder the two of them are in and then the javascript will pick up the png file made by the python program

Comment: Maybe I misread your comment. Do I need an additional bit of code to have the py file to pick up the post request?

Comment: Well yeah its not connected at all at the moment, unless you have some other bit of code that does, but from what I can tell, these two are not connected

Comment: What do I need to connect them?

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Does the python program need to be running in the background?

Comment: I mean yeah that too but you also have to modify the code

Comment: Is there a quick answer for running the python program in the background when running the server command in a different shell?

Comment: What commands are you exactly running? You should only run the flask python script and then that should start up the entire server right?

Comment: ```def main():
    port = 8000
    bp.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
    print(get_post_javascript_data());``` So, run this, and then where do i run the html/javascript?

Comment: I think your code is very messed up right now

Comment: Shoot. Do you have any further suggestions?

Comment: I can help you rewrite everything but it would be very difficult to do it in stack overflow, and plus I don't think your reputation points are high enough to start a discussion

Comment: Could I provide anything to verify that I am legitimate? I'm just a student at a major US university. I can show you a website that the school I am in has where some of my work is. You could join my private zoom or something like that. Just throwing ideas out.

Comment: Do you have discord?

Comment: Yes. Zero#0321 :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm under the impression that I think you may have misunderstood how HttpRequests work. You don't reference the file, you just reference the route, here is a fix:

JavaScript Code:

```
    fetch("/javascriptPost", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers:{'Content': 'application/JSON'},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        'Company' : document.getElementById("search").value,
        'Time' : time
      })
    }).then(function(response)
    {
      console.log(document.getElementById("search").value);
    })
```

Python Code:

```
@bp.route('/javascriptPost', methods = ['POST'])
def get_post_javascript_data():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json()
        ticker = data['Company']
        timespan = data['Time']
        print (ticker)
        print (timespan)
    return getPlot(ticker, timespan)
```

Comment: I made a typo earlier! Please copy the new edit